# Is event.preventDefault cancelling change events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I have a certain situation I want to clarify for myself, and I would be glad if anyone has any experience with this issue and is willing to explain it to me.

I have a textarea that has a `change` event handler:

```
textarea.bind('change', function(event){
    // do something
});
```

Hypothetically, what if I have some sort of a click event handler that catches all user clicks:

```
$(document).bind('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Will this handler also cancel `blur` and `change` events for a textarea if a user clicks out of it with his mouse? And if it will, how can I prevent this from happening?

**Update:** Thank you for your answers, I can not say that I tried it, but I have a similar situation and I am trying to rule out possibilities why `change` is not firing on my textarea. In my case there is a `change` handler that doesn't work if I click on an area in which all `click` events are prevented by default and replaced with custom behaviour.

Comment: I have keydown and change events on a text input and if I add preventDefault() in the keydown event, change events never fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will only prevent the default browser behavior for the 'click' event.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe the default browser behaviour also is to trigger the `blur` event.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetically, what if you just tried it? (answer: it won't, as stated just before me)

If you don't want users to be able to leave a inputfield (which sounds like strange user interaction to me), you might be able to just set focus after a `blur`/`change` event - perhaps you would need a small timeout to let the event finish first. I would not recommend it, but it's always worth a *try*.