# Why Internet Explorer stop after a function when use event.preventDefault() or return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a little code like this:

```
$("input#checkbox").change(changeCheckbox);

function changeCheckbox() {

    var inputCheck = $("input#checkbox"),
        button = $("input#button");

    if (inputCheck.is(":checked")) {

        button.hide();

    } else {

        button.show();
    }
}
```

This work perfect in all modern Browser and IE 8

But when I use this one with `event.preventDefault();`:

```
$("input#checkbox").change(changeCheckbox);

function changeCheckbox(event) {

    event.preventDefault(); // <-- Here

    var inputCheck = $("input#checkbox"),
        button = $("input#button");

    if (inputCheck.is(":checked")) {

        button.hide();

    } else {

        button.show();
    }
}
```

or I set `return false;`

```
$("input#checkbox").change(changeCheckbox);

function changeCheckbox() {

    var inputCheck = $("input#checkbox"),
        button = $("input#button");

    if (inputCheck.is(":checked")) {

        button.hide();

    } else {

        button.show();
    }

return false; // <-- Here
}
```

then the function only works once and I can do nothing more with this in (only) **Internet Explorer 8**

**Can someone explain to me why this happens?**

And i have a lot of other functions and use similar codes with `event.preventDefault();` and `return false;` at the end and there are OK...

I use this jQuery Version: `jquery_1.10.1.min.js`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean the handler is not triggered again, and subsequent clicks will not do anything? Please be more specific about "*I can do nothing more*".

Comment: @Bergi - In this example I can`t checked the Checkbox after call the function once

Comment: @dqf13g32g Well, that's the default action of a `type="checkbox"` -- it switches between checked and unchecked. Preventing that instructs it not to change. Or, am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - Ok and why I have problems with `return false;`? Thanks

Comment: @dqf13g32g: Because [`return false` *is* `event.preventDefault()` in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: @Bergi - Thank you for your answers - Now it is clearer for me! :-)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: However it indeed is a bug in IE. A `change` event should not reset the checkbox when preventing the default action, only a `click` event would. [Try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/8NSDa/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone explain to me why this happens?

It's a bug in Internet Explorer (what else). [The `change` event is supposed to be not cancelable](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents), in contrast to `click` events (see [Is event.preventDefault cancelling change events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950798/is-event-preventdefault-cancelling-change-events), [jQuery/Javascript: Click event on a checkbox and the 'checked' attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786223/jquery-javascript-click-event-on-a-checkbox-and-the-checked-attribute) and [Why does preventDefault() on a parent element's click 'disable' a checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767083/why-does-preventdefault-on-a-parent-elements-click-disable-a-checkbox)). IE8 however does prevent the checkbox from being (un)checked when the `change` event is canceled. [Try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/8NSDa/).

How to work around that? Just remove `e.preventDefault()` [(or `return false`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) from your code. I don't see any reason to use it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is to show/hide `#button` based on the value of `#checkbox`. You can do it this way. Very less lines of code as compared to your code

```
$('#checkbox').on('change', function() {
    $('#button').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L6xuW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code for IE8:

```
if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
else event.returnValue = false;
```

Since you are using jQuery you can use the built-in cross-browser event fix:

```
event = $.event.fix(event);
```

See: http://www.jquerysdk.com/api/jQuery.event.fix

Comment: He's using jQuery, so `preventDefault` is fine.

Comment: But does jquery_1.10.1 support old IE?

Comment: @Musa [Yeah](http://jquery.com/browser-support/). It's 2.x that doesn't support IE 8 and older.